# Sending stdin to subprocess in python script

Tags: python, macos, unix, terminal, subprocess

I have a python script which requires the opening of another terminal window to send some commands. Stackoverflowers have already gotten me that far:

```
import subprocess
server_terminal = subprocess.Popen(['open','-a','/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app','/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app']) #Not sure about the inelegance of the doubled path, but it does open another terminal window, which I need.
```

The next step that I need is to send this terminal some commands so that I can get a local server set up on the user's desktop. Having some significant troubles figuring how to control this subprocess.

Can anyone direct me to the method I would use to make this terminal subprocess take stdin from me? I would prefer to avoid 3rd party modules.

Edit: Some context -- My major goal is to open a [selenium server](http://seleniumhq.org/) in a separate terminal window so that I can issue it commands. I already know how to control the server once it's started, I just can't figure out how to automatically start one.

Thanks for all your help!

Comment: I don't think you can control a terminal through STDIN.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Any other way that I could?

Comment: Getting a window handle, faking keystrokes or something like that. Maybe you can also provide a script as a command line argument to the shell. But probably what you rather want is to run a simple shell script (and no terminal at all). Can you tell us more about what you want to achieve?

Comment: Yes, thank you Niklas. What I'd like to do is open a selenium server (which is a jar file that runs in an open terminal), in order than I can run a firefox browser through some testing of websites. I have no experience with subprocess and am baffled though. Additionally, I couldn't find anyone doing what I am trying to do, which most likely means I'm misguided somewhere.

Comment: All I really need to do is get the server running without human input. Once I do that I know everything I need to in order to control the server. Just having trouble getting it started automatically...

Comment: Just create a simple [shell script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shell_script) that executes the server. If you want, you can even do it from inside Python: `subprocess.Popen(['java', '-jar', path_to_jar])` or `os.system('java -jar /path/to/jar')` if you need to see the output.

Comment: Here is the full command that I would put into a terminal window: `java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.0b3 -firefoxProfileTemplate 'path-to-profile'` ... Do you mind issuing an answer that is capable of reproducing that with the subprocess module?

Comment: Is the input to Selenium a canned set of commands, or do you need to control it interactively?

Comment: I won't need output from the server. I can get all the feedback I need from my script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `Popen` to start the server directly:

```
selenium_jar = '/full/path/to/selenium-server-standalone-2.0b3.jar'
path_to_fifo_profile = '...'

# start external process
p = subprocess.Popen(['java', '-jar', selenium_jar, 
                              '-firefoxProfileTemplate', path_to_fifo_profile,
                     ])
# wait for it to finish before exiting
p.wait()
```

If you want to see the output, you can use `os.system` instead:

```
os.system('java '
          '-jar /path/to/selenium-server-standalone-2.0b3.jar '
          '-firefoxProfileTemplate /path/to/profile')
```

Comment: Don't forget `stdin=subprocess.PIPE`. Also, `communicate` should take some input data.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Selenium, but in that case, shouldn't you use `wait` rather than `communicate`?

Comment: @larsmans: Yes, you're right, as a long-running application, the server could generate quite some output. Should have read the warning.

Comment: Damn, I'm getting a file not found error: `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Comment: @Mike: With the first version? That would mean it doesn't find your `java`. Is it in your PATH? Try specifying the full path to find out (you can get the full path by executing `which java` in a shell).

Comment: Hmmm... Still no success. All the paths are correct though: 
`p = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/java' '-jar', selenium_jar, '-firefoxProfileTemplate', path_to_fifo_profile])`

Comment: @MikeHalpin: Does one of the paths start with `~` or contains an environment variable? `Popen` without `shell=True` doesn't resolve these. You can add `shell=True` or use the resolved paths.

Comment: No their just standard path names :/  ... Here is the output with shell=True: `/Users/Halpin/Programs/Servers/selenium-server.jar: /usr/bin/java-jar: No such file or directory`

Comment: @Mike: Ah, now I see. The problem was in my code, I forgot a comma. `'java' '-jar'` is interpreted as a single string, `'java-jar'`. Fixed it.

Comment: It works! However it opens in my current terminal window, which I am assuming will end my python script's interpretation. Any chance it could open a new window? Mac has an open command shown in my post. Any chance we can incorporate that here? I obviously don't know what all the pieces mean in your code.

Comment: Ah' never mind. It's great! I got my input back. Hence the wait command. Thanks for being patient with me. Your code works great.